# How to publish SMS message in Amazon SNS directly to a US-based phone number?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have been using the boto3 SNS client to publish messages to phone numbers and they are working for non US phone numbers but they do not work for US phone numbers. I have specified the origination numbers but they do not seem to be working.

```
    sns_client = boto3.client("sns", region_name="us-west-2") 
    try: 
        response_sns = sns_client.publish( 
            PhoneNumber=PhoneNo, 
            Message="Hello," + first_name + ". Your       OTP is " + str(OTP) + ".", 
            MessageAttributes={ 
            "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": { "DataType": "String", "StringValue": "Transactional", }, 
            "AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber": { "DataType": "String", "StringValue": "+120******", }, }, ) 
        print(response_sns) 
    except Exception as e: 
        print("could not send sms") 
        print(e)
```

The use of US phone numbers doesnot show any errors in lambda logs. Just that the messages are not received.

Comment: Is the phone number supplied in E.164 format?

Comment: few things to check.
1) SNS delivery status from SNS screen (if it shows at all)
2) that phone no is subscribed or not
3) format (as mentioned by  jarmod)
4) SNS spending limit
5) check with mobile-career for support
hope you have tested with different numbers...

Comment: Have you completed either the [10DLC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-10dlc.html) or [Toll Free](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-tfn.html) registration?  You can't just make up a sending number anymore in the US

Comment: You can [View Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html) to get more details.

Comment: I  have an active origination number and that is that is what I am using in the AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber field. Is there anything else I need?

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the MessageAttributes parameter of the publish method, you also need to set the AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber attribute to a valid U.S phone number that is registered with Amazon SNS. well that should work.

Comment: Additionally, I believe it's a requirement now to use a registered short code as of a couple of years ago within the US. Other countries may have similar restrictions, for example China.